# Issue with instance and class variable states when using JNI

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm currently writing some Android code that uses JNI and I'm having difficulty how class and instance variables work. If I execute the following code I would expect the code to print a value of "18" but I always receive a value of "0". Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

// Java code

```
SampleClass sc = new SampleClass(18);
sc.printId() // returns 18, as expected
sc.nativePrintId() // returns 0, why?!
```

// Java Class

```
public class SampleClass
{ 
    private int mId = -1;        

    public FFmpegMediaPlayer(int id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    public void printId() {
        System.out.println("id: " + mId);
    }

    public native void nativePrintId();
}
```

// JNI C++ code

```
static void nativePrintId(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("wseemann/media/SampleClass");

    jmethodID printId = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "printId", "()V");

    env->CallVoidMethod(clazz, printId); // always prints zero?
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the object, not the class, to `CallVoidMethod`.

Use:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(thiz, printId);
```

Also, you should get the class from the object, not from `FindClass`.

Use:

```
jclass clazz = env->GetObjectClass(thiz);
```